# Java: How to save a date into MySQL without timezone conversion?

Tags: java, mysql, timezone, mybatis, localdate

I'm saving a birthday with Java8 + MyBatis + MySQL5.7. My code is like this:

```java
// 'birthday' is a DATE column
@Insert("insert into MyTable (id, birthday) values (#{id"}, #{date})")
void saveDate(int id, LocalDate date);

@Select("select birthday from MyTable where id=#{id"}")
LocalDate loadDate(@Param("id") int id);
```

And the code to save and load a date.

```java
final int id = 1;
final LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2020, 1, 3);

repo.saveDate(id, date);
LocalDate dateFromDB = repo.loadDate(id);

System.out.println(date);        // 2020-1-3
System.out.println(dateFromDB);  // 2020-1-2
```

I noticed that the value of "dateFromDB" is always one day before the "date". I think it's caused by the timezone conversion. Since my application is at UTC+8, while DB is using UTC. By using DATETIME instead of DATE, I can see the date '2020-1-3' is saved as '2020-1-2 16:0:0'.

So the question is **how to avoid timezone conversion when saving a date like a birthday?**

----------------- Updated 2020-02-20 ------------------------------------

So far, I found 4 ways to do it:

1. Add a parameter `noTzConversionForDateType=true` to avoid the conversion only for date type. This is the best way but **it only applies to version 5.1**. I really don't understand why it's removed from version 8.0... ([document](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-properties-changed.html))
2. Add a parameter `serverTimezone=GMT%2B8` use the client timezone (UTC+8) as the server timezone. The conversion still happens but it changes nothing. The problem is `TIMESTAMP` columns would also be affected.
3. Add a parameter `-Duser.timezone=UTC` to JVM. The problem is similar to #2.
4. Send `LocalDate` value as `String`. Update the `saveDate` function as below (only change the type from `LocalDate` to `String`):

```java
@Insert("insert into MyTable (id, birthday) values (#{id"}, #{date})")
void saveDate(int id, String date);
```

Then convert the date to a `String` before calling `saveDate`:

```
String dateString = date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"));
repo.saveDate(id, dateString);
```

Note that the data type in DB is still `DATE`. The benefit of this way is only the `birthday` column will be affected. The problem is that the code is not elegant and it might lead to performance issues for a large data set.

Comment: You either have to adjust the time zone configuration of your database or convert the date from/to the desired time zone before/after storing/loading the data. Maybe, a `TIMESTAMP` would do, too, could work with an `Instant`. I think you should convert, maybe using a `ZonedDateTime` or an `OffsetDateTime` in Java and let the database store everything in UTC.

Comment: @KenZhang It's a known issue with Connector/J 8.0.x. See https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=93444 . Adding `serverTimezone` to the JDBC URL is the workaround for now. In your case, it would look something like `jdbc:mysql://yourhost:3306/dbname?serverTimezone=GMT%2B8`. You should click 'Affects me' on the ticket.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are connecting to MySQL using a connection string like the following

`jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb?useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=YOUR_TZ`

Should do some conversion for you